# Very strange mysql wait after moving to different server

Tags: magento-1.9, database

I moved my webshop to a different dedicated server, same specs as my old one. Now I am testing it but there is a very strange wait before loading the page. The page load is more then 30 seconds, on the other server 2 seconds. This is what I got from my hoster but I am not sure how to troubleshoot.

```
MariaDB [(none)]> show processlist \g
+------+---------------+-----------+---------------+---------+------+-------+------------------+----------+
| Id | User | Host | db | Command | Time | State | Info | Progress |
+------+---------------+-----------+---------------+---------+------+-------+------------------+----------+
| 2255 | da_admin | localhost | NULL | Query | 0 | NULL | show processlist |
0.000 | | 2256 | magext_gerben | localhost | magext_gerben | Sleep | 28 | |
NULL | 0.000 | | 2257 | magext_gerben | localhost | magext_gerben | Sleep | 25
| | NULL | 0.000 |
+------+---------------+-----------+---------------+---------+------+-------+------------------+----------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)

MariaDB [(none)]> show processlist \g
+------+---------------+-----------+---------------+---------+------+--------------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+----------+
| Id | User | Host | db | Command | Time | State | Info | Progress |
+------+---------------+-----------+---------------+---------+------+--------------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+----------+
| 2255 | da_admin | localhost | NULL | Query | 0 | NULL | show processlist |
0.000 | | 2256 | magext_gerben | localhost | magext_gerben | Query | 12 |
Sending data | SELECT `e`.*, IF(at_is_active.value_id > 0, at_is_active.value,
at_is_active_default.value) AS `is_a | 0.000 | | 2257 | magext_gerben |
localhost | magext_gerben | Query | 9 | Sending data | SELECT `e`.*,
IF(at_is_active.value_id > 0, at_is_active.value, at_is_active_default.value)
AS `is_a | 0.000 |
+------+---------------+-----------+---------------+---------+------+--------------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+----------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: not enough technical data. you need to provide some more profiler, error log, process strace information.

Comment: Ok thanks for the tip and I installed AOE Profiler and found the issue :-) fishpig wordpress module version check. adminhtml_wordpress_checkVersion

Comment: I installed AOE Profiler and found the issue :-) fishpig wordpress module version check. adminhtml_wordpress_checkVersion

Comment: I have exactly the same issue now with the Fishpig wordpress module. Would you mind letting me know how you solved the issue? Its grinding my server to a stand still :(

Comment: I wish the Magento team would open up `Bluefoot CMS Editor / Page Builder` to community edition and clients wouldn't ask for wordpress to manage CMS content :( Fishpig is great but I hate having to use it

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://magento.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://magento.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/157890)

Answer (score 0):

I installed AOE Profiler and found the issue :-) fishpig wordpress module version check. adminhtml_wordpress_checkVersion